# Visual Studio 2013 Cordova Project

Tags: cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I am running Windows 7 x64.  I have installed Node.js. I just installed Visual Studio 2013 with the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps CTP 2.0.

When I run a simple 'Hello World' app I get these errors:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 
connect ECONNREFUSED 
Error installing local npm package
```

Comment: Could you add details about: (1) Did you install all the 3rd party tools through the installer, and were there errors? (2) What platform and deployment target are you trying to build you app for?

Comment: Maybe u need to set proxy configuration of npm?

Answer (score -1):

At first build after installation, MDHA tries to download a few required Cordova dependencies through npm. In this case, the `ECONNREFUSED` seems to suggest, either:

- You do not have network connectivity on your machine
- You are behind a proxy (common for enterprises) that is refusing connections

Once you identify the issue above, just try to build again and it should proceed successfully.